# android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce this error is coming in chinese devices

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I m facing this in chinese devices.This is native ANR libandroid_runtime.so That always come in chinese devices like Realme,Oppo,Vivo,Mi,Etc.
I'm using this Firebase crashlytics version
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.9.2'

[image]

```
main (native):tid=1 systid=26052 
#00 pc 0xc8b38 libc.so (__epoll_pwait + 8) (BuildId: f24f65acf653c409ca4332aced817a71)
#01 pc 0x168d4 libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int) + 180) (BuildId: 0c269320029489b4040b2307f9282499)
#02 pc 0x167b8 libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**) + 112) (BuildId: 0c269320029489b4040b2307f9282499)
#03 pc 0x14d19c libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int) + 44) (BuildId: c646cf84c51fc07b4bb81680ce4aed68)
#04 pc 0x43e154 libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline + 148) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#05 pc 0x20fc1f4 memfd:jit-cache (android.os.MessageQueue.next + 244)
#06 pc 0x204a76c memfd:jit-cache (android.os.Looper.loopOnce + 188)
#07 pc 0x209a9c libart.so (nterp_helper + 1948) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#08 pc 0x47063a framework.jar (android.os.Looper.loop + 178)
#09 pc 0x209334 libart.so (nterp_helper + 52) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#10 pc 0x1b4dd6 framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main + 270)
#11 pc 0x434a00 libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub + 576) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#12 pc 0x467134 libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long) + 1960) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#13 pc 0x466964 libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*) (.__uniq.165753521025965369065708152063621506277) + 48) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#14 pc 0x43e154 libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline + 148) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#15 pc 0x20a2b0 libart.so (nterp_helper + 4016) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#16 pc 0x2a944e framework.jar (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 22)
#17 pc 0x20b074 libart.so (nterp_helper + 7540) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#18 pc 0x2af672 framework.jar (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 714)
#19 pc 0x434a00 libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub + 576) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#20 pc 0x57df48 libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list) + 900) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#21 pc 0x5f194c libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list) + 160) (BuildId: 28c5aa8a2e8fc5df069f717d6e94f7fe)
#22 pc 0xafb28 libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...) + 120) (BuildId: c646cf84c51fc07b4bb81680ce4aed68)
#23 pc 0xbb214 libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool) + 948) (BuildId: c646cf84c51fc07b4bb81680ce4aed68)
#24 pc 0x2580 app_process64 (main + 1320) (BuildId: c4e0717e77dbaf6f3710de1f5d169e0e)
#25 pc 0x71538 libc.so (__libc_init + 96) (BuildId: f24f65acf653c409ca4332aced817a71)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
```